# Symfony 2.6 - Flot chart doesn't populate properly from JSON

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm, flot, symfony-2.6

I'm trying to populate Flot Pie chart with JSON created from doctrine query result, but unsuccessfully.
Here are details...

Controller:

```
$resultJson = json_encode($query);

return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array( 'result' => $resultJson ));
```

JSON result:

```
[{"label":"project 1","data":"5"},
 {"label":"project 2","data":"1"},
 {"label":"project 3","data":"1"}]
```

Javascript:

```
var data = '{{ result}}';
var options = {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 0.8,
                    formatter: function (label, series) {
                        return '<div style="...">' +
                        label + ' : ' +
                        Math.round(series.percent) +
                        '%</div>';
                    },
                    background: {
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $.plot($("#flot"), data, options);
```

Current result (undefined labels and one more than it should): http://oi61.tinypic.com/28srjut.jpg

Desired result: http://oi59.tinypic.com/sncwtx.jpg

Comment: So, wait, you're writing with Twig the data results, correct? Shouldn't you delete the single quote marks around the twig code? Because otherwise javascript will take it as a string and not an object.

Comment: @user1231958 removing single quote marks gives me on `var data` _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &_ ...
`var data = JSON.parse({{result}})` - same SyntaxError

Comment: Can you post the generated javascript code AFTER the page is rendered? You can easily see this in your browser, by using the "view source" feature (most browsers have this).

Comment: @user1231958 Here it is (with single quote marks):

`var data = '[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;project 1&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;5&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;project 2&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;project 3&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}]';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the single quotes as stated and you need the output to be non-escaped.  Twig is automatically escaping your double-quotes to be 'safe', but that's not what you want.  It should be:

```
var data = {{ result|raw }};
```

As a side note, I wrote a small [Flot library](https://github.com/jasonroman/flot) and [Symfony Flot bundle](https://github.com/jasonroman/flot-bundle) that helps convert your PHP arrays into common Flot formats like pie, line, bar charts, etc.  It may be of some use to you to help prepare the data for Twig.

Comment: With `{{ result|raw }}` double-quotes are here...
`var data = '[{"label":"project 1","data":"5"},{"label":"project 2","data":"1"},{"label":"project 3","data":"1"}]';`
...but the Flot pie has same incorrect values.
I think that problem is with double-quotes on numbers.
https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format

I'll check your bundle and library...

Comment: Remove the single quotes. It should be `{{ result|raw }}`, not `'{{ result|raw }}'`

Comment: That's it, thank you guys.
`var data = {{ result|raw }};`
...
`var data = [{"label":"project 1","data":"5"},{"label":"project 2","data":"1"},{"label":"project 3","data":"1"}];`